How to fix overlapped top heading with contents?
The following screenshot illustrates the issue.

I want the header to be about 30mm tall and the footer to be about 15mm tall. The heading should not overlap with the body.
Using \setlength{\headheight}{20mm} can fix the overlapped issue but the footer is pushed out of the page.
What is the proper way to solve it?
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[
    a5paper,
    hmargin=10mm,
    bottom=15mm,
    top=25mm,
  bindingoffset=15mm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}



\pagestyle{fancy}

%\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}


\fancyhead[LE]{\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-a}} 
\fancyhead[RO]{\includegraphics[width=25mm]{example-image-a}} 
\fancyhead[C]{Center Header} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}

\fancyfoot[L]{Left Footer}
\fancyfoot[C]{Center Footer}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 


\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{One}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Two}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{document}


Like this:

You need to add specification for headheight, headsep, reduce topargin and then include them to settings for page layout. Also it will be better to define height of images in head than define their width:
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[
    a5paper,
    hmargin=10mm,
    vmargin={10mm, 15mm},                       % changed
    headheight=20mm, headsep=5mm, includehead,  % added
    bindingoffset=15mm
            ]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{2pt}

\fancyhead[LE]{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{example-image-a}} % changed
\fancyhead[RO]{\includegraphics[height=20mm]{example-image-a}} % changed
\fancyhead[C]{Center Header} 
\fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} 
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}

\fancyfoot[L]{Left Footer}
\fancyfoot[C]{Center Footer}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}} 
\pagestyle{fancy}


\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\subsection{One}
\lipsum[1-3]
\subsection{Two}
\lipsum[4-5]
\end{document}

